# Count column in Matrix visual showing 1 instead of 0

Tags: matrix, powerbi

My data is structured like below. It is a table of companies where audits have been conducted and the subsequent defects that have been raised. For some companies, no audits will have been performed, therefore the Audit column will show null.

```
Company    Audit    Defect
Company A  Audit 1  Defect 1
Company A  Audit 1  Defect 2
Company A  Audit 1  Defect 3
Company B  Audit 2  *null*
Company B  Audit 2  Defect 1
Company C  *null*   *null*
Company D  Audit 1  Defect 1
```

I want to show this information in a matrix table, with Company in the 'Rows' and a count of distinct Audits in the 'Values'. I'd expect the above to show

```
Company        Count of Audits   
Company A      1  
Company B      2  
Company C      *null*   
Company D      1
```

For some reason, when there is no audit listed against the company in the table, my count is still showing '1'. I want to add the Audit Title to the matrix as a drill down. When I do this, it shows a blank line under those where there are no Audits, however still counts as 1?

[image: example]

[PBIX file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mt6q5sajscfzry7/stack_example.pbix?dl=0)

Is this something wrong in my source data that I need to fix, or a setting I can adjust in the matrix?

Comment: Can you share a sample .pbix with the problem?

Comment: Sorry, David, I don't see an option to upload a pbix here? Is there somewhere I can upload to and provide a link?

Comment: Upload to a free upload site and then post a link here.

Comment: Thanks, David. Original post updated to include.

Comment: Your file doesn't match your sample data posted. Can you explain exactly what you expect to see with a specific company?

Comment: Hi David. Apologies I made an error creating the dummy data file, have reattached to the original post. Essentially, I don’t understand how in the matrix Company 19 shows a count of 1, when there are no audits listed? Similarly, Company 2 shows a distinct count of 3 when there are 2. It seems Distinct Count will count the null value, is there a way round this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure instead.

[image]

```
Measure =  COUNTAX( VALUES(Sheet1[Audit]), Sheet1[Audit])
```